# Laravel FFMpeg - Unable to load FFMpeg in file error

Tags: php, laravel, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to integrate FFMpeg into a Laravel project but am getting the error when I call the end point:

`FFMpeg\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException: Unable to load FFMpeg in file /Users/me/Desktop/video/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFMpegDriver.php on line 55`

What I've done:

`brew install ffmpeg` - installed FFMEG locally, can confirm that this works when using terminal

Fresh Laravel install `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app`

Install php ffmpeg `composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg`

install Laravel ffmpeg `composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg`

added FFMPEG to providers and aliases in  `app.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\ServiceProvider::class,
    ...
];

'aliases' => [
    ...
    'FFMpeg' => ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg::class
    ...
];
```

and then my controller is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use FFMpeg;

class VideoController extends Controller
{
    public function makeVideo()
    {

        FFMpeg::fromDisk('songs')
    ->open('yesterday.mp3')
    ->export()
    ->toDisk('converted_songs')
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Audio\Aac)
    ->save('yesterday.aac');
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

which is the example they give on git. if I call the end point I get the above error. Has anyone got any ideas what's wrong or how to debug? The logs don't give me any more information!

Comment: This means executable can't be found

Comment: @dtwoo I have the same problem. ffmpeg works fine on jobs but when I try to use it within controller I get the same error. could you solve the this?

Comment: @MohsenMirhosseini yes, managed to get it working by adding the path to my .env file - obviously replace the location to your local copy of ffmepg

FFMPEG_BINARIES=C:\bin\ffmpeg.exe
FFPROBE_BINARIES=C:\bin\ffprobe.exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not able to find your FFMpeg executable. Try adding the path to `FFMPEG_BINARIES` and `FFPROBE_BINARIES` in your `.env` file.

**Edit 2022-06-13**
Most times, just adding this two lines in your `.env` file will do.

```
FFMPEG_BINARIES=/usr/bin/ffmpeg
FFPROBE_BINARIES=/usr/bin/ffprobe
```

Comment: This worked for me also. Though my binaries were stored in a different location on the server. To find the location of the binaries run this in bash "which ffmpeg" and "which ffprobe"

Answer (score 2):

It's possible **FFmpeg** is not install on your OS.
If you are using Ubuntu or Linux then run the command below to ensure **FFmpeg** is installed

`ffmpeg -protocols`

If you get

```
Command 'ffmpeg' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Then install **FFmpeg** by running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

**Note on file path.**

The default path for FFMpeg::open('') is `storage\app`

I was able to get this to work without setting binaries or making extract config settings

Also, you only need this `composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg` to get everything installed, it handles other depencies